# Issues with ConnectedComponents in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have been trying to trouble shoot this issue for a week and still have made no progress. I have a land classification I created for a large study area (Nova Scotia) and the tiles containing small portions of the study area are not included. The extent of the image should look like this:

[image]

however, when exported to QGIS it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see corners are missing. After over a week of scratchig my head on this, it appears that my image shrinks in size once I used the connectectedComponent function. I also tried a pixel based approach to see if it was indeed ConnectedComponents that was the issue, and I had the same issue with the pixel based approach. Portions of the image were getting masked out. I have no idea what is going on and this issue is significant enough that I may migrate to another platform if I can't figure it out (I don't want to).

I tried the following:

1. I specified the region in the export.
2. I still had the issues so I specified region: AOI2.geometry() and that didn't work.
3. I zoomed out all the way so the entire image was in the view screen and corners were still missing.
4. I thought maybe it's something to do with storage so I converted from a 32 bit to 8 bit and issue persists.

UPDATE.----------------

It appears that once I compute cluster stats that the dimensions of the image decrease. Perhaps this is the step which is resulting in the issue?

Script is here:

```
//Step 2 Import Predictor Variable composite into this script to work around
//memory issues
//Map.addLayer(NSSentComp);
//Calculate slope and visualize slope to aid with assessment
var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(DEM)

//Calculate Chrome DEM developed by Kevin Kikaldy McGuigan

var atanslope = slope.atan()
var StdDev5m  = atanslope.reduceNeighborhood({
    reducer:ee.Reducer.stdDev(), 
    kernel: ee.Kernel.circle(5, 'meters')
  });
  var max15m = StdDev5m.focalMax(15, 'circle', "meters")
print(slope)
var μ30m = max15m.focalMean(30, 'circle', "meters")
var image = μ30m.rename('μ30m')
 var chrome = μ30m.subtract(atanslope)


//Display NSSentComp to confirm it was exported/imported correctly
var NSSentComp = NSSentImages.addBands(DTW.rename('WAM'))
                .addBands(TRI.rename('TRI'))
                .addBands(DEV150.rename('DEV150'))
                .addBands(DEV500.rename('DEV500'))
                .addBands(CHM.rename('CHM'))
                .addBands(DEM.rename('DEM'))//Testing adding DEM
                .addBands(DEV1000.rename('DEV1000'))
                .addBands(MSI.rename('MSI'))
                .addBands(chrome.rename('chrome'));
print(NSSentComp, 'NSSentComp')

var bandsToKeep = NSSentComp.bandNames().filter(ee.Filter.neq('item', 'NDVI'));

// Select and rename the "NDVI" band. This will prevent me from resampling 
var NSSentComp = NSSentComp.select(bandsToKeep)
                                   .addBands(NSSentComp.select('NDVI').rename('ndvi'));
var NSSentComp= NSSentComp.clip(AOI2) 
// Print the renamed composi
//var NSSentComp = ee.Image('projects/ee-jrgallop/assets/NSSentComp_Temp')
Map.addLayer(NSSentComp)//Includes all predictor variables at 5 m
Map.addLayer(NSSentImages)//just sentinel and slope at 5 m
print(NSSentComp)
//OPTIONAL - add additional predictor variables to composite created 00.WM.

//NSSentComp = NSSentComp.addBands(Curv.rename('Curv'));
//SEGMENTATION - Set Sentinel-2 4 band mosaic for segmentation
//Set seeds for segmentation and apply softening
var seeds = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.seedGrid(10, 'hex');
var kernel = ee.Kernel.gaussian(3);
//Use RGBI and slope bands to create objects.
var segbands = [ 'slope', 'B2_median', 'B3_median', 'B4_median', 'B8_median']//'slope',REMOVED MSI for TESTING ,compare to chrome
var segbands = NSSentComp.select(segbands);
//var segbands = NSSentComp.select(['B2_median', 'B3_median', 'B4_median', 'B8_median', 'chrome']).bandNames();
print(segbands, "segbands");
//Smooth the segmented image
var segcompsmoo = segbands.convolve(kernel);

//Segment Sent/Slope Composite
var snic2 = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC({
  image: segcompsmoo,
  //size:5,
  compactness: 0.1,  
  connectivity: 4,
  neighborhoodSize: 20,
  seeds: seeds
}).reproject({crs: 'EPSG: 26920',
scale: 5
});
//visualize and inspect segmented image
print(snic2, "Snic2")

// Define the visualization parameters.
//var vizParams = {
  //bands: ['B2_median_mean', 'B3_median_mean', 'B4_median_mean'],
  //min: 0,
  //max: 0.5,
 // gamma: [0.95, 1.1, 1]
//};

var clusters3 = snic2.select('clusters');
Map.addLayer(snic2.randomVisualizer(), null, 'clusters3', false);
print(clusters3, "clusters3")
//Calculate stats per cluster for all predictor variables calculating mean and Stdev
var NSSentComp = NSSentComp.addBands(clusters3.rename('clusters3'))

var allStats = NSSentComp.reduceConnectedComponents({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().combine({
 reducer2:ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
  sharedInputs:true
  }),
  labelBand: 'clusters3',
  maxSize: 512  
  })
print(allStats, "allstats")
var Clusterstats = allStats; 
print (Clusterstats, "Clusterstats");  //print to check bands were created as expected
Map.addLayer(Clusterstats);
//OPTIONAL - CREATE FEATURE POINTS IN GEE 
var IMGTraining = Swamp.merge(FMarsh).merge(SaltMarsh).merge(Fen).merge(Bog).merge(upland).merge(Water);
//OPTINAL - export to asset if going to use in other models
Export.table.toAsset({
  collection: IMGTraining,
  description: 'Trainingdata0126',
  assetId: 'Trainingdata0126',
});
//print(FMSTraining, "FMSTraining");
//Import training samples and train reduced segmented image above
var trainVector = table3//table 7 performed poorly (salt marsh over predicted. Used table6//ee.FeatureCollection ('projects/ee-jrgallop/assets/FMSTrainpoints');
var trainPoints = Clusterstats.sampleRegions({
  collection: trainVector,
  scale: 5,  //This is the scale we want the clusters to be processed at
  tileScale: 16, //want tilesize to be large enough to contain clusters, but too large will produce memory errors
  geometries: true,  //adding this enables you to export to asset
  });
  
  print(trainVector, "TV")
// Export to Asset requires the feature collection to have geometries. Rename output.
Export.table.toAsset({
  collection: trainPoints,
  description: 'SegTest0124',
  assetId: 'SegTest0124',
});
  
print(trainVector, "TrainVector")
 
  //Split training points into training and validation
  //var trainPoints = Table;
  var trainPoints = trainVector.randomColumn();
  var split = 0.2;
  var training = trainPoints.filter(ee.Filter.gt('random', split));  //80% training
var validation = trainPoints.filter(ee.Filter.lte('random', split));  //20% validation
//print(trainPoints)
//print(validation, "validation")


Export.table.toAsset({
  collection: validation,
  description: 'validation',
  assetId: 'validation',
});
 
var predictionVar = 
//test - pixel-based approach
//['B2_median', 'B3_median', 'B4_median', 
//'B8_median','slope','WAM','CHM', 'DEV150', 'DEV500', 'DEV1000', 'REIP', 'NDWI', 'ndvi', 'EVI', 'NARI'];



//FINAL MODEL
[ 'B2_median_mean', 'B2_median_stdDev', 'B3_median_mean', 
 'B4_median_mean', 'B4_median_stdDev', 'B8_median_mean',
 'B8_median_stdDev', 'slope_mean', 'slope_stdDev', 'REIP_mean', 'REIP_stdDev', 
 'NARI_mean', 'NARI_stdDev','NDWI_mean', 'NDWI_stdDev', 'EVI_mean',  'EVI_stdDev', 
  'ndvi_mean','ndvi_stdDev', 'WAM_mean', 'TRI_mean', 'TRI_stdDev', 'DEV150_mean', 
 'DEV150_stdDev', 'CHM_mean', 'CHM_stdDev',  'DEV500_mean','DEV1000_mean',
'DEM_mean','DEM_stdDev', 'DEV1000_stdDev', 'MSI_mean', 
 'MSI_stdDev','NDII_mean','chrome_mean', 'chrome_stdDev'];
// I REVIEWED CORRELATION COEFFICIENT IN R AND SYSTEMATICALLY REMOVED VARIABLES WITH HIGH CORRELATION WITH 
//HIGH IMPORTANCE VARIABLES. I ran 20 iterations (IT) and observed accuracy. I kept variables that were not 
//decreasing the accuracy and removed variables that decreased accuracy
//'B3_median_stdDev',

/// IT1 - remove 'slope_mean' - kept in model due to decrease in swamp accuracy and marginal changes 
//IT2 - remove 'WAM_mean' - kept in model due to decrease OA when removed
//IT3 - removed 'WAM_stdDev' -  REMOVED from model due to increase accuracy when removed.
//IT4 - removed 'ndvi_mean',- - kept in model due to decrease in OA.
//IT5 - removed 'DEV500_stdDev - Removed from model, OA stayed the same with minor changes in class accuracy, mainly increases in class.
//IT6 - removed 'CHM_stdDev',-  kept in model due to decrease in OA.
//IT7 - removed B2_median_mean - 'B2_median_mean' - kept in model due to decrase in OA
//IT8 - removed EVI_mean-'EVI_mean', kept in model due to decrease in OA
//IT9 -  removed 'EVI_stdDev', - kept in model due to decrease in OA
//IT10 - remmoved ndvi_stdDev - 'ndvi_stdDev', kept in model due to decrease in OA
//IT11 - removed 'DEV500_mean' - kept in model due to decrease in OA
//IT12 'DEV1000_mean',- keptin model due to decrease in OA
//IT13 'NDII_stdDev' - removed from model due to redundancy
//IT14 'B2_median_stdDev', - Kept due to decrease in accuracy
//IT18 -removed 'NARI_stdDev', - kept in due to decrease in accuracy
//IT19 - removed 'NDWI_stdDev',- kept in model due to decrease in accuracy
//IT20 - removed  'B3_median_stdDev' - kept out of model due to redundancy


//VARIABLES TO ADD TO MODEL. IGNORE ABOVE.

//OA 89% AND INCREASED TO 90% AND IMPROVEMENT OF PEATLAND IDENTIFICATION. SEE NOTES.
//
//Use this script below if getting string error with training data
var training = training.map(function (ele){
  
var class_as_number = ee.Number.parse((ele.get('Class')));
  
  return ele.set('Class', class_as_number);
  
});

var trainedRF = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest({numberOfTrees: 1000}).train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'Class',  //Name of the field with the class labels
  inputProperties:predictionVar
});
print (trainedRF.explain());
print(trainedRF, "trainedRF")

//Classify

var classifiedRF = Clusterstats.classify(trainedRF).float();
//var classifiedRF = classifiedRF.clip(FMSBndry);
//Print image to assess
print(classifiedRF, 'CLRF1')
//Validation error matrix
var validated = validation.classify(trainedRF,'classification');
var testAccuracy = validated.errorMatrix({
  actual:'Class', 
  predicted: 'classification'});
print('Validation error matrix: ', testAccuracy);
print('Validation overall accuracy: ', testAccuracy.accuracy());
print('Validation consumer accuracy: ', testAccuracy.consumersAccuracy());
print('Validation producer accuracy: ', testAccuracy.producersAccuracy());
print('Kappa Coefficient: ', testAccuracy.kappa());
//-------------------------------------------------
// Get Relative Variable importance chart


var importance = ee.Dictionary(trainedRF.explain().get('importance'))

var sum = importance.values().reduce(ee.Reducer.sum())

//var relativeImportance = importance.map(function(key, val) {
//   return (ee.Number(val).multiply(100)).divide(sum)
//  })
  
var relativeImportance = importance.map(function (band, importance) {
  return ee.Number(importance).divide(sum).multiply(100)
print(relativeImportance, 'Relative Importance')})

var importanceFc = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(null, relativeImportance)
])

var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byProperty({
  features: importanceFc
}).setOptions({
      title: 'RF Variable Importance',
      vAxis: {title: 'Importance'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Bands'}
  });

print(chart, 'Relative Importance');


Map.addLayer(slope, { palette: ['blue', 'yellow', 'red'], min:0, max: 10.714}, 'slope');
  
//Convert to 8-bit to speed up export time//TEST
var classifiedRF = classifiedRF.uint8();
//smooth output usinog a modal filter
//first pass
var classifiedRF = classifiedRF.focalMode(3, 'circle')
//second pass
var classifiedRF2 = classifiedRF.focalMode(3, 'circle')
//Mask upland pixels for inspection
var classifiedRF= classifiedRF2.updateMask(classifiedRF2.neq(5));

 //Define pallete for the classification
var classifiedRFPalette = [
  'green', // 1/ Swamp green
  'grey',  // 2 / bog / grey
  'yellow', // 3 / fen
  'red', // 4 fresh water marsh/ red
  'brown', // 5/upland/brown
  'blue', // 6/water
  'black' // 7/salt marsh
];
//Due to size map won't load. You will need to export and then import to view. I have added a recent classifier (classifier 7), to the map to give you an idea of what it will look like.

Map.addLayer(classifiedRF, {palette: classifiedRFPalette, min: 1, max: 7}, 'Clasifier');

//Clip to study area

var classifiedRF = classifiedRF.clip(AOI2);

print(classifiedRF, 'CLRF')

//export to asset 
Export.image.toAsset({
  image: classifiedRF,
  description: 'ModelF2',
   region: AOI2.geometry(),
  scale: 5,
  crs:'EPSG: 26920',
  maxPixels: 9889194154
  });
  
//OPTIONAL - UPLOAD ANY TRAINING DATA 
//Map.addLayer(MTRIVAL)
//Map.addLayer(MTRIVAL2)

Map.addLayer(classifiedRF7, {palette: classifiedRFPalette, min: 1, max: 7}, 'Clasifier7');
Map.addLayer(chrome,{ palette: ['black', 'white'], min:-1.496, max:0}, 'chrome');
```

Link is found here:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/3a9d65d2adbadf5c614032713895a93f?noload=1

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really the best answer, but I was able to come up with a work around.

The issue was that two of my predictor variables (CHM and WAM)had a limited extent that didn't include the missing corners but all my other variables did. I don't fully get it but I guess connected components can't computer when some variables are no data? This is the image of the CHM variable which has the same extent of the output I am getting.

[image]

Either way, I ended up just running the model without using CHM and WAM variable and clipped it to the missing corners. I then mosaiced to the classified image I showed above. It's not the perfect solution but for such a small area that is largely water, I am not too worried if one small offshore island is missing two variables. If you know of a better solution let me know.